How to obtain a PDE from a solution
I am trying to do something similar to this question but for a PDE. Specifically, I have these some equations and also know the answer as it's from a paper but cannot understand it or redo it.
Consider 4 functions $u(t,x),v(t,x),w(t,x),s(t,x)$. All are functions of space and time. I have 3 DEs and 1 equation. I'm wondering why we even need to convert the equation to a DE first of all. Second of all, if we do, how do we do it and why does the $\Delta x$ only appear sometimes? My main confusion is surrounding $w$ and how it's being pulled into the equations.
The expression for $u$ I am given is
$$u(t,x)=v(t,x)-s(t,x)$$
The 2 DEs I have, one in $t$ (already in good shape, doesn't even get used it seems) and one in $x$ are:
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = -2 u$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -3w$$
I so have a $\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}$ expression but it's not important as it is fully defined. It's just needed to fully define the system.
What the paper does for finding time-varying expressions for $u,v$, and $w$ is somehow take everything to one side in the first expression and then multiply by $w$, which has an expression for its $x$-derivative. I'm not sure why this was done or why $\Delta x$ appears in the first but not the second. Here are the two time-varying PDE expressions for $u$ and $w$ as per the paper:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = (v - s - u)\frac{w}{2 \Delta x}$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \left(-3w-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)\frac{w}{2}$$$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = \left(-2(v-s)-\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)\frac{w}{2}$$
I am not getting how the x-varying DEs and equation are being converted to time-varying ones. I just see the terms being collected within brackets for each system.
